# Reading stdout after terminating a process

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to launch a process, let it run for some time and then read its output (the last output is ok, I don't need everything). I tried to use the following code:

```
def connect(interface):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['mycommand', interface], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    time.sleep(10)
    proc.terminate()
    output, err = proc.communicate()
    print(output)
```

Unfortunately, every time it gets stuck when reading the output. I also tried to use `proc.read()` instead of `communicate()` but it didn't solve the problem.

What's the best way to handle output in this case?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python

Comment: Very interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that the issue came from the buffer. As indicated in the subprocess module documentation:

> This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE and the child
>   process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting
>   for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use Popen.communicate()
>   when using pipes to avoid that.

There are two solutions:

- Use the `bufsize` argument to set the buffer to a size large enought to store all the output generated during the time you wait.
- Use `readline()` to read the output and flush the buffer during the waiting time. If you don't need it just discard the output.

I choose the second approach ; my code is as follow:

```
def connect(interface):
    stdout = []
    timeout = 60
    start_time = time.time()
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['mycommand', interface], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
    while time.time() < start_time + timeout:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()
        stdout.append(line)
    proc.terminate()
    print(output)
```